# Active a virtual environment then run a python script with VBA & Excel

Tags: python, vba

I have a python script that I need to run on a spreadsheet via VBA, but before it runs, I need to activate a specific virtual environment for this.

This is my attempt so far but it does not seem to do anything. This is python3.8 on macos.

```
Sub runpython()
Dim sheet As String
Dim iso As String
Dim PScript As String
Dim PExe As String

iso = "test"
sheet = "test"

PExe = "~/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python3.8 "
PScript = "~/Desktop/test/test.py "

script_args = "-i " & iso & " -s " & sheet

Shell ("source ~/Desktop/test/bin/activate && " & PExe & PScript & script_args)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to activate a virtual environment. The code below should be sufficient:

```
Shell (PExe & PScript & script_args)
```

The `activate` script modify the `PATH` variable which is useful to launch commands like `python`, `ipython` or other cli scripts.

Comment: This is going to be used on several other devices, all of which have this virtual environment set up to work with a module that is proprietary. The script I am running uses the module that is installed in the virtual environment, along with its reqs. That is why I need to activate the environment.

Comment: Read the `activate` script. There is no magic about how to find modules. Try to launch from a console without activate your virtualenv, `~/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python3.8 -m pip list`, you should see your proprietary module.

Comment: Ohhh that's right! Thank you! Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I glad to read it works and do not be sorry! The community is there for that.

Comment: Ok so update. I was a bit hasty! The script works fine when I run it in terminal like you said with no venv, however when I run it as a macro it is not working properly. Is it a problem that I have it on the sheet instead of in a module?

Comment: From a blank workbook, try to launch `Shell (~/Desktop/test/venv/bin/python3.8 -m pip)`

Comment: Should I be trying to assign it to a range or something so I can see the output? I am rather new with excel and vba.

Comment: I'm so sorry too, I work only on Linux. I can't help you this time.